# SQL add columns of each record together

Tags: sql

To be blunt I don't know SQL however I don't want the answer, I want to work it out myself.

Here's the question:

Write a SQL query to calculate the number of goals for each team.

players

```
id name team_id goals
1 Joel 1 3
2 Ed 2 1
3 Simon 2 4
```

teams

```
id name
1 New Zealand
2 London
```

What I'm asking for is an arrow to information that will allow me to solve the question.

I've tried looking myself but I don't even know the correct terminology to ask the question, googling 'write sql to add fields for each row' just seems to return about adding columns or inserting.

Comment: Look at `GROUP BY` and aggregate functions.

Comment: +1 for your wish **not** to get an answer... Look for `INNER JOIN` to get the "teams" table connected with the "players" table via `teams.id` and `players.team_id`. Than look for `GROUP BY` and `SUM`

Comment: check here to read more about Shnugo Keywords suggestion and examples http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first try to JOIN your tables(id in Teams will be linked to TeamId in Players.) based on the foreign key columns.

Then you need to do the GROUP BY and use the aggregate function SUM to get the goals for each team.

So your query will be like:

```
select t.name, sum(p.goals) as cnt, 
from players p inner join teams t on p.teamid = t.id
group by t.name
```

Comment: Are you sure this is enough for an answer? Especially if there are comments already stating exactly the same?

Comment: I'm going to tick this as the answer I came up with was almost exactly the same (from reading source material), thanks @all for pointing me in the right direction. I decided not to read this till I came up with an answer.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to group players by teams : use **t1.id=t2.id** to join values in the tables, and then group theme by "**BROUP BY**" t.name.

Then : user "**SUM(value)**" function who sum values .

```
select teams.name,sum(players.goals) from players,team where player.team_id=teams.id group by teams.name;
```

Comment: When teaching people only now introduced to SQL, avoid using implicit join syntax . Use only the proper syntax of joins